# Err Num 111 Connection refused when trying to connect to mongodb in external server - (Port is on)

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

I am getting the following error -

> ServerSelectionTimeoutError: servername.ie:27017: [Errno 111]
>   Connection refused.

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb//servername.ie/27017")

dblist = client.list_database_names()
print(dblist)
```

When I checked weather the port exist in the server using the following command

```
netstat -an|grep LISTEN|grep 27017
```

I got the following:

[image]

But I am not sure why I am getting Connection refused. Please let me know if I know anything

Edit:

When I tried as per the suggestions in first comment

```
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

I am getting

```
Unit mongod.service could not be found
```

But I have started this service in another terminal at port 27018 and getting the below message.

```
I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27018
```

Comment: Are you sure mongod service is running? `sudo systemctl status mongod`

Comment: @metmirr, Please check my updated question.